# Count points in polygon - sum is giving NULL results

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

When doing the "count points in polygon" I set up a sum of one the parameter. The problem is that at the end I get "NULL" for this column. Everything else is working well. I tried with integer, whole or real numbers.

Comment: which gis software are you using? did you check if the field you want to get the numbers from are integer/real numbers as well?

Comment: Sorry I'm using QGIS 2.14.
Yes the field I want to get the numbers from was integer, but i tried in real and whole numbers too. Doesn't change anything

Comment: Add link to the QGIS documentation of that function.

Comment: the documentation I found: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_analysis_tools/countpointsinpolygon.html

Why I want to do it: https://geolabs.wordpress.com/2016/03/16/how-to-count-overlapping-points-in-qgis-cluster-point-map/

Comment: Perhaps a bug? Could you try installing a newer version and running the same tool as 2.14 is fairly old now?

Comment: I tried on 2.18 but the functionality of aggregating some data doesn't exist anymore. So it might come from a bug, I may check with an older version to see.

On the other hand, do you have an idea on how to reach the goal of couting overlapping point to increase readability of the maps?

Comment: are you using the same crs for both layers?

Comment: A workaround would be to assign an ID to each polygon (if you don't already have one) and then Join Attributes by location (Join ID Attribute to Points within Polygon). You basically tell every point in which polygon it is. 
In the last step you count the points with the same ID from the Join.

Comment: QGIS 2.18 has a tool called  "count points in polygon (weighted)". It seems that you want to aggregate only one attribute and then that toold should be OK for you.

Answer (score 1):

So according to the answers, it seems that:
 - it's not possible to do it directly from the "count points in polygon" tool in Qgis 2.14 (due to a bug?)
 - the feature does not exist directly in QGIS 2.18 so it's needed to use the "count points in polygon (wighted)" tool from the processing

Thanks user30184 for the answer and all the other for the help.